# Javascript closures & stack unwinding

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand the concept of closures of java script in depth.

```
function foo(){
     let temp = 5;
     let bar = function _bar(){
          console.log('temp:=', temp);
     }
     return bar;
}

let ref2Bar = foo();
ref2Bar();

o/p:
temp:=5
```

From the above sample code snippet, bar() has closer over foo(). ref2Bar got the reference of bar() and executing it from global scope can access the lexical scope of foo().

Now I'm coming from the stack winding & un-winding stuff. When foo() is complete, it is supposed to be popped out of stack but as the reference of bar() is active in the lifetime of this file, it sounds like the foo scope is still accessible. I'm very curious to know how this is handled. Also, if there are more closures, will there be a fair chance of running Out Of Memory?

Comment: How many closures would you need to run out of memory? I'm presuming a billion or two. How many are you intending to create? Also the closure itself is destroyed when all references to it fall out of scope, so it's up to you to not retain references you don't need.

Comment: You have this phrased backward - `foo` is a closure over `bar` because `foo` wraps around it to create the outer scope. But you seem to be thinking about the scopes correctly.

Comment: @DanLowe: Nope, the proper terminology is indeed that `_bar` closes over the lexical scope of `foo` (that contains `temp` and `bar`) and is therefore a closure.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, perhaps I need to do some refresher reading on the subject...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When `foo()` is complete, it is supposed to be popped out of stack

Yes, it's no longer active.

> but as the reference of `bar` is active in the lifetime of this file, it sounds like the `foo` scope is still accessible.

Indeed it is.

> I'm very curious to know how this is handled

The variable environment ("scope") that contains the variables that are closed over needs to be allocated on the heap, not on the stack. The execution context ("stack frame") that is popped off the call stack merely contains a pointer to it.
The variable environment is therefore not garbage-collected until `_bar`/`ref2bar`s reference to it is destroyed.

> Also, if there are more closures, will there be a fair chance of running Out Of Memory?

Yes, every closure is an object and takes memory space. If you create many closures that close over variables that have large values, you can indeed incur a memory leak. I wouldn't call that a "fair chance" though, you would need very very many of them or very very large ones.